# Is there a public issue tracker for Github.com?

Tags: github

Does GitHub have a public issue tracker for bugs / enhancements to the github.com website itself?

If not, what **is** the suggested way for reporting bugs / requesting enhancements to the github.com website?

Answer (score 1):

Someone already asked that question.
The reply was:

> You can ping us at support@github.com.

Source: https://github.com/holman/ama/issues/152